# Scale and Crop Image max-width

Tags: html, css

I want to take a large source image of any dimensions, scale the height down to 400px, crop it to the middle now-scaled-down 300px of width, and display it on a webpage.

For this landscape source image:

https://www.sitebuilderreport.com/assets/facebook-stock-up-446fff24fb11820517c520c4a5a4c032.jpg

This [code](https://jsfiddle.net/5pxj0yoh/) works perfectly:

HTML

```
<div class="myscaled" style="background-image: url('https://www.sitebuilderreport.com/assets/facebook-stock-up-446fff24fb11820517c520c4a5a4c032.jpg');</div>
```

CSS

```
.myscaled {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

However for this portrait source image:

https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_800_800/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAFrAAAAJGE4YTQ0ZThjLWRkM2MtNGM1OS1iNGMwLTZiZjliYmRkZTY2Nw.jpg

The same [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5pxj0yoh/1/) crops the top and bottom:

I guess it's because the height to width ratio is more than 4:3, so it's cropping the height to give a width of 300. What I want in that case is preserve all the height and just display whatever width there is. So basically I want the height to be 400 and the max-width to be 300.

Any ideas how I can do this? Maybe trap the image inside a fixed size div and let the extra image spill out?

## EDIT

I've also tried [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/5pxj0yoh/4/), which works fine for the portait, but I can't get the oversized width of the landscape to center in the container div.

HTML

```
<div class="mydiv">
<img class="myimg" src="https://www.sitebuilderreport.com/assets/facebook-stock-up-446fff24fb11820517c520c4a5a4c032.jpg"></div>
```

CSS

```
.myimg {
  height:400px;
}

.mydiv {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size: contain;` , maybe it should help.

Comment: Contain fixes the portrait image to give the desired behaviour, but then the landscape one is broken.